# Include meta tag outside the HTML tag

Tags: html, meta-tags, tags

Can I include the meta tag of the IE 5 content in outside the HTML tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5">
<html>...</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can but it is not valid HTML.

Comment: I think the question meant to ask “does it work?”, and the reason for asking might be the inability to insert the tag into its proper place, due to some odd restrictions somewhere. I would expect it to work, though the DOM might not contain the `meta` element (or might have it wrongly placed). But it would seem to be simple matter to test it; you only need to test as many IE versions as you can get.